# C++ : Why I can't print a const char* with sprintf?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constants, printf

What am I missing here ? It's driving me nuts !

I have a function that returns a **const char***

```
const char* Notation() const
{
    char s[10];
    int x=5;
    sprintf(s, "%d", x);
    return s;
}
```

Now in another part of the code I am doing this :

```
.....
.....
char str[50];       
sprintf(str, "%s", Notation());
.....
.....
```

but **str** remains unchanged.

If instead I do this :

```
.....
.....
char str[50];
str[0]=0;
strcat(str, Notation());
.....
.....
```

**str** is correctly set.

I am wondering why **sprintf** doesn't work as expected...

Comment: Maybe one idea is to change the function to : void Notation(char* buffer) const and work on the caller-provided char buffer.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clear, a "working" sample was given, which shows effort, and the actual problem sample is given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to return an array allocated on stack and its behaviour is undefined.

```
const char* Notation() const
{
    char s[10];
    int x=5;
    sprintf(s, "%d", x);
    return s;
}
```

here `s` isn't going to be around after you've returned from the function `Notation()`. If you aren't concerned with thread safety you could make `s` static.

```
const char* Notation() const
{
    static char s[10];
    ....
```

Comment: I thought that the buffer is allocated at compile time and stays there for the lifetime of the application. If this is not true, then wouldn't this mean that every function returning a non-global const char* is wrong ? (and dangerous)

Comment: Any function that returns an automatic const char* is dangerous. There are many other ways of returning buffers - for example static and also newly allocated buffer using malloc. however if you return malloc'd buffers you've to manage cleanup properly.

Comment: @Wartin: I think you are thinking of string literals.  If, for example, you said: `return "foobar";` -- That would be safe, as the string "foobar" lasts through the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @hawk : Do you think that making the buffer static will do the job ? I am not concerned with thread safety (but I wonder why it matters ;-)

Comment: @Wartin - Roughly speaking static inside a function extends the lifetime of the variable to end of the program. however the visibility is just like an automatic variable. The reason it's not threadsafe is simply that multple threads could be concurrently executing in the function and stepping on each other.

Comment: I agree with hawk. If you use static, thread safety is up to you. If you have only one thread though, declaring the s as static will do it. However, if you are not VERY concerned with speed, I suggest you use a smart pointer like boost::shared_array

Answer (score 5):

In both cases, it invokes undefined behavior, as `Notation()` returns a local array which gets destroyed on returning. You're *unlucky* that it works in one case, making you *feel* that it is correct.

The solution is to use `std::string` as:

```
std::string Notation() const
{
    char s[10];
    int x=5;
    sprintf(s, "%d", x);
    return s; //it is okay now, s gets converted into std::string
}
```

Or using C++ stream as:

```
std::string Notation() const
{
    int x=5;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << x;
    return oss.str(); 
}
```

and then:

```
char str[50];       
sprintf(str, "%s", Notation().c_str());
```

The benefit (and beauty) of `std::ostringstream` (and `std::string`) is that you don't have to know the size of output in advance, which means you don't have to use magic number such as `10` in array declaration `char s[10]`. These classes are safe in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

`char s[10]` in `Notation` is placed on stack so it gets destroyed after exit from `Notation` function.  Such variables are called [automatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).  You need to save your string in heap using `new`:

```
char *s = new char[10];
```

But you have to free this memory manually:

```
char str[50];
const char *nt = Notation();
sprintf(str, "%s", nt);
printf("%s", str);
delete[] nt;
```

If you really use C++ then use built-in `string` class like [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771858/458723) suggested.  If you somehow restricted to raw pointers then allocate buffer outside `Notation` and pass it as *destanation* parameter like in `sprintf` or `strcat`.

Comment: While that would solve the problem, it's a terrible idea.  If he tried to use the function the way he is now, it would be a guaranteed memory leak.

Comment: Yes, that is it.  Since the question is about C++ then `string` is the best choice.